# Silverlight 5 dynamic stream URI setting

Tags: c#, silverlight

I'm not familiar with Silverlight (5) but think I'm close to getting what I'm trying to do working. Grateful for any help.

Basically, I need to pass a dynamically generated smooth stream URI into the player and set "Media Source" correctly.

Steps I'm taking..

Client invocation, a single key-value pair..

```
<param name="InitParams" value="mediaurl=http://playready.directtaps.net/smoothstreaming/TTLSS720VC1/To_The_Limit_720.ism/Manifest" />
```

MainPage.xaml..

```
<!--Media:PlaylistItem DeliveryMethod="AdaptiveStreaming" MediaSource="mPlayer" /-->
```

App.xaml.cs

```
public Dictionary<string, string> PageData = new Dictionary<string, string>();
private void Application_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
{
    var paramValues = e.InitParams;

    foreach (var param in paramValues)
    {
        this.PageData.Add(param.Key, param.Value);

    }

    this.RootVisual = new MainPage();

}
```

MainPage.xaml.cs..

```
public partial class MainPage : UserControl
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        App currentApp = (App)Application.Current;

        string uriString = currentApp.PageData["mediaurl"];

        MessageBox.Show(uriString);

        Microsoft.SilverlightMediaFramework.Core.Media.PlaylistItem item = new Microsoft.SilverlightMediaFramework.Core.Media.PlaylistItem();

        item.MediaSource = new Uri(uriString, UriKind.Absolute);

        item.DeliveryMethod =
          Microsoft.SilverlightMediaFramework.Plugins.Primitives.DeliveryMethods.AdaptiveStreaming;

        //Add PlaylistItem to the Media playlist
        Microsoft.SilverlightMediaFramework.Core.SMFPlayer SMFPlayer = new Microsoft.SilverlightMediaFramework.Core.SMFPlayer();

        SMFPlayer.Playlist.Add(item);

        SMFPlayer.Play();


    }
}
```

Visual Studio 2015 Compiler doesn't complain with `MainPage.xaml.cs` but it doesn't work. 
The Silverlight player plays static URIs fine, but not URIs passed in `InitParam`.

Comment: Hoping this is not a stupid question. The static and passed in initparam values you tested are the same?

Comment: Same URI with both static and passed in initparam.  My code breaks in MainPage.xaml.cs for some reason as uriString is being set OK. Simply trying to bind the MediaSource MainPage.xaml to uriString.

Comment: Does it give an error message?

Comment: Hi there, no build errors, (both XAP and test page build fine). When I run the project in VS I get an error in the browser (can't find the "mediaurl" key). Workaround is to edit the test page with the InitParam URI as I'm not sure how to generate IniParams within the IDE. I'm wondering if I'm assigning the InitParam URI correctly to bind it to the Media Source attribute via creating the mPlayer instance.,  .

Comment: Check out this tutorial http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/216403/Enhancing-Media-Experience-in-Silverlight-with-Mic

Comment: Updated the post with an actual Smooth URI, commenting out "Media:PlayListItem", and updating code based on the linked codeproject article, changing some of the MainPage code behind as "PlayListItem" not reference-able in IDE. The  project compiles fine but not streaming.

Comment: Loading the TestPage HTML in IE11's F12 Developer Tools  shows there's no network traffic in Play request,  nor scripting errors in IE debugger.  The InitParam is being set OK (MessageBox.Show) but failing to update the PlayList using the updated MainPage.xaml.cs code.   Static MediaSource assignment work fine eg : <Media:PlaylistItem DeliveryMethod="AdaptiveStreaming" MediaSource="http://playready.directtaps.net/smoothstreaming/TTLSS720VC1/To_The_Limit_720.ism/Manifest"/>

Comment: @Nkosi, grateful for any further suggestions with resolving the issue in assigning the InitParam URI dynamically in Silverlight code? Code behind is setup with dynamic URI verified passed in.

Comment: provided an answer

Comment: Any feed back on the provided answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say that setting the url manually like this works...

```
<Media:PlaylistItem DeliveryMethod="AdaptiveStreaming" MediaSource="http://playready.directtaps.net/smoothstreaming/TTLSS720VC1/To_The_Limit_720.ism/Manifest" />
```

in that case then you need to update view so you can make control accessible by name from code behind (IDE).

```
<Media:PlaylistItem x:Name="playListItem" DeliveryMethod="AdaptiveStreaming"/>
```

and then in the code behind, reference that control

```
public partial class MainPage : UserControl
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        App currentApp = (App)Application.Current;

        string uriString = currentApp.PageData["mediaurl"];

        MessageBox.Show(uriString);

        //reference item by name
        Microsoft.SilverlightMediaFramework.Core.Media.PlaylistItem item = this.playListItem;

        item.MediaSource = new Uri(uriString, UriKind.Absolute);
        //...other code
    }
}
```

The other example from the link I sent you did it like this.

In **MainPage.xaml**

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White" 
   xmlns:smf="http://schemas.microsoft.com/smf/2010/xaml/player">
    <smf:SMFPlayer HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0" 
         x:Name="sMFPlayer" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" />
</Grid>
```

In **MainPage.xaml.cs**

```
using Microsoft.SilverlightMediaFramework.Core.Media;
using Microsoft.SilverlightMediaFramework.Plugins.Primitives;
//...
public partial class MainPage : UserControl
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        App currentApp = (App)Application.Current;

        string uriString = currentApp.PageData["mediaurl"];

        var item = new PlaylistItem();
        item.MediaSource = new Uri(uriString, UriKind.Absolute);
        item.DeliveryMethod = DeliveryMethods.AdaptiveStreaming;

        //Add PlaylistItem to the Media playlist
        sMFPlayer.Playlist.Add(item);
        sMFPlayer.Play();
    }
}
```

Comment: @Nikoski I'm probably going to move this to a new thread. I tried both approaches and  now can only play audio not video, for URIs that I can play smooth streams statically assigned in XAML. The original question has been answered, in how to pass dynamic smooth stream URIs into Silverlight player and thank you for your advice.  Why I can't see video from multiple smooth streaming sources in Silverlight 5, nor player controls being operative, but hear audio and see video and audio packets in Fiddler is perplexing.

Comment: OK cool. Sorry it didn't answer your question. If it was of any use to you don't forget to upvote. Hope you find a solution to your overall problem soon.

Comment: Upvoted and new thread FYI @ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36767344/no-smooth-streaming-video-only-audio-in-code-behind-with-silverlight-5