# No smooth streaming video only audio in code behind with Silverlight 5

Tags: c#, silverlight

Backstory in [Silverlight 5 dynamic stream URI setting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36646767/silverlight-5-dynamic-stream-uri-setting).

My goal (as an artifact from the link) is to resolve why I'm rendering audio fine but not video for smooth streaming files in dynamically rendered (InitParam) smooth URIs.

Basically, I need to pass a dynamically generated smooth stream URI into the player and set "Media Source" correctly. Which I believe I've done.

Testing statically linked MediaSource="http://playready.directtaps.net/smoothstreaming/TTLSS720VC1/To_The_Limit_720.ism/Manifest"/  works fine for both video and audio.
However dynamically generating the PlayListItem doesn't.

The code..

**MainPage.xaml**

```
<UserControl x:Class="SilverlightApplicationDPCS.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
xmlns:Core="clr-namespace:Microsoft.SilverlightMediaFramework.Core;assembly=Microsoft.SilverlightMediaFramework.Core" 
xmlns:Media="clr-namespace:Microsoft.SilverlightMediaFramework.Core.Media;assembly=Microsoft.SilverlightMediaFramework.Core" 
mc:Ignorable="d"
d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="400">

<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White" xmlns:smf="http://schemas.microsoft.com/smf/2010/xaml/player">
    <smf:SMFPlayer HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0" 
     x:Name="sMFPlayer" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" />


    <Core:SMFPlayer AutoPlay="True" AutoLoad="True">
        <Core:SMFPlayer.Playlist>

        </Core:SMFPlayer.Playlist>
    </Core:SMFPlayer>

</Grid>
```

**MainPage.xaml.cs (overriding the consumption of the InitParam param for debug purposes statically setting uriString)**

```
public partial class MainPage : UserControl
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        App currentApp = (App)Application.Current;

        string uriString =      "http://playready.directtaps.net/smoothstreaming/TTLSS720VC1/To_The_Limit_720.ism/Manifest";


        if (sMFPlayer.Playlist.Count > 0)
            sMFPlayer.Playlist.Clear();

        sMFPlayer.Playlist.Add(new PlaylistItem
        {
            MediaSource = new Uri(uriString, UriKind.Absolute),
            DeliveryMethod = DeliveryMethods.AdaptiveStreaming
        });

        sMFPlayer.Play();
```

All references below are version 2.012.0605.0, other than Microsoft.Web.Media.SmoothStreaming.dll  version 2.0.157.18

**Project References:**

Microsoft.SilverlightMediaFramework.Core.dll

Microsoft.SilverlightMediaFramework.Plugins.dll

Microsoft.SilverlightMediaFramework.Plugins.SmoothStreaming.dll

Microsoft.SilverlightMediaFramework.Utilities.dll

Microsoft.Web.Media.SmoothStreaming.dll

**Compiler Environment:**

Microsoft Media Platform: Player Framework

Silverlight 5

Windows 7

Visual Studio 2015

Browser: Run-time Internet Explorer 11.

Fiddler shows video and audio smooth fragments..

GET http://playready.directtaps.net/smoothstreaming/TTLSS720VC1/To_The_Limit_720.ism/QualityLevels(688000)/Fragments(video=60050000) HTTP/1.1

GET http://playready.directtaps.net/smoothstreaming/TTLSS720VC1/To_The_Limit_720.ism/QualityLevels(128000)/Fragments(audio=61765079) HTTP/1.1

**From the above StackOverlow link, where I'm left is:**

Why I can't see video from multiple smooth streaming sources in Silverlight 5, nor player controls being operative, but hear audio and see video and audio packets in Fiddler is perplexing.

Grateful for any ideas to fix this.

Comment: Surprised this appears difficult to do in Silverlight 5, as in set a Smooth URI in code behind for Microsoft's SMF Player, instead of statically setting in XAML. Static setting work great, even for PlayReady protected Smooth URIs in IE 11 and Firefox. Unfortunately neither protected or unprotected smooth works in my player's simple code behind URI assignment builds, and at a loss to figure out why.

Comment: Hi there, after 8 days and 73 views and no response, just sending my question out again. Seems frustratingly close to getting resolution. Could anyone answer on why my MainPage.xaml/MainPage.xaml.cs is not setup correctly to render video URI dynamically assigned in C# code behind using latest SMFPlayer binaries? Very basic code behind.